# MySQL How to calculate rate of change between 2 count functions?

Tags: mysql

I have a real estate sales table (Mutation) with Date (DateMutation) information.

I need to find the rate of change between number of sales in the first and second trimesters.

so far I have:

```
SELECT count(*) as T2
FROM mutation
WHERE DateMutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30';

SELECT count(*) as T1
FROM mutation
WHERE DateMutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31';
```

But I have no idea how to apply this formula: ((T2 - T1) / T1)*100 to get a coherent answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mutation
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,DateMutation DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mutation (datemutation) VALUES
('2020-04-01'),
('2020-06-30'),
('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-15'),
('2020-03-31');

SELECT (
        SUM(datemutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30') 
      - SUM(datemutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31')
       )
       /SUM(datemutation BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31')*100 x 
  FROM mutation;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
| -33.3333 |
+----------+
```

Edit: Note that SUM and COUNT do different things - even where dates are concerned...

```
 SELECT SUM(datemutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30') x
      , COUNT(datemutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30') y
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN datemutation BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-06-30' THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END) z
   FROM mutation;
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This works. Thanks very much. Took me a moment to figure it out.

Comment: I hadn't realised that for dates sum and count do the same thing.

Comment: SUM and COUNT do different things. In MySQL `SUM( x BETWEEN a AND b)` is shorthand for `SUM(CASE WHEN x BETWEEN a AND b [is true] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. You can take this new-found knowledge and apply to your next problem; it's essentially the same.

Comment: Incidentally, it's good form on SO to upvote answers that are useful in some way (especially when the respondent has a miserably low reputation) :-(. Additionally, where an answer solves the issue, it's useful to mark it as accepted.